# Assign variable to an array from Active Directory

Tags: php, arrays, active-directory

I am having trouble figuring out how to correct an issue I am having with the following code. I am trying to list the names and emails of all the people in my Active Directory.  This code works.  However, I also get the following warning when it is executed.

Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array.

From what I have read online I need to set " $name['mail']['0'] = "Not Found";" to an array. My question is how would I go about doing this. I have tried every way I could think of with no success.  If anyone could provide me with some feedback it would be greatly appreciated.

```
foreach ($results as $name) {
  if (!isset($name['mail']['0'])){
       $name['mail']['0'] = "Not Found";
  }
  $allnames[$name['cn']['0']]['mail'] = $name['mail']['0'];
```

Comment: Which line is the error on

Comment: in my full page of code its line 27 but this is just a snippet of code from my page. from the code i posted it would be line 3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to assign the "Not Found" value BACK into the results of the ldap query you are running.

When I wrote code to get user information from ldap, I always inserted values into a different array (getting the fields I wanted) and then displayed THAT array out in the HTML:

```
foreach ($results as $name) 
{
    if (isset($name['mail']['0']))
    // Check if it IS set, rather than not set and then append the data.
    {
        $allnames[$name['cn']['0']]['mail'] = $name['mail']['0'];
    }
}
```

Then after you have all the fields you want you display the `$allnames` array.

Having said that, when I construct the array of user information, I make the array much much simpler - knowing what I want to display out, more along the lines of this:

```
foreach ($results as $name) 
{
    if (isset($name['mail']['0']))
    // Check if it IS set, rather than not set and then append the data.
    {
        $allnames['mail'] = $name['mail']['0'];
    }
}
```

You (or at least I) don't need to follow the ldap structure when making the array of information I have gathered, but rather I want to get specific fields from the directory and then display them by what they are - for example when I output the value in *mail* I might want to hyperlink it as an email address, so I keep it in an array element that I know by key and refer to later.